# How to revert to python 2 in conda root environment?

Tags: python, conda

I created a new `python3` environment to install python 3; due to the incompatibility between `conda` and `Windows PowerShell`, I installed python 3 in both of the `root` and `python3` environment by accident. Is it possible to revert to python 2 in the `root` environment?

```
C:\Users\Nick>conda info --env
# conda environments:
#
python3                  C:\application\anaconda\envs\python3
root                  *  C:\application\anaconda


C:\Users\Nick>python -V
Python 3.3.5 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`conda install python=2` should do the trick. Definitely check and make sure that all packages downgraded successfully by inspecting the output of `conda list` for versions that contain the `py3` string.  For any packages that contain `py3` in the version string, you should probably just uninstall/reinstall them.

(Hypothetical) Example:

The third column in `conda list` is the python version.  If you see:

`anaconda-client           1.1.2                    py35_0    defaults`

then you should

`conda remove anaconda-client`

followed by

`conda install anaconda-client` so that it installs the python 2 version.

Then `conda list` should show the `anaconda-client` line like this:

`anaconda-client           1.1.2                    py27_0    defaults`.