# Can Python 2 still be installed for use with Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

This may be somewhat of a novice question. I don't have a lot of python knowledge, but run a script written by a previous employee of ours. It was written in Python 2 and there are issues larger than using parentheses when trying to rewrite to Python 3. However, we can no longer install Python 2 through Anaconda and many of us use Spyder to run python scripts. We will hire someone to rewrite soon, but need to run the scripts now.

I went through the instructions listed here [How to revert to python 2 in conda root environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706991/how-to-revert-to-python-2-in-conda-root-environment#), but nothing changed with respect to Python version. Is it still possible to downgrade to Python 2 and have Spyder run that Python version?

I appreciate any insight, thank you.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: 1. why do you need to use spyder? 2. Are you using a virtual environment? 3. Does your company use docker?

Comment: 1. Many staff are accustomed to using R studio, so Spyder seems to let them use a similar layout in running code without learning the ins and outs of Python (which wouldn't be part of their job duties). 2. We do not use a virtual environment. 3. We do not use docker.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create a virtual environment.

Open your conda cli and write this command:
`conda create -n legacy python=2.7 anaconda`
where **legacy** is the name I've arbitrarily chosen for the virtual environment

After this runs, you can activate the virtual environment with `conda activate legacy` and you'll be running in python `2.7`

running the command `spyder` should then open spyder in the `legacy` environment running 2.7

Python 2.7 is past end of life, if you're connecting to the internet I'd strongly consider deprecating this code asap python 2.7 does not reliably back port security updates.

Comment: Thank you. We will be hiring someone to rewrite the scripts to Python 3!  We just need a short term solution at this time.

Comment: My suspicion from your numpy question is you're in a government/consulting space. If you need someone with experience (and credentials) in that space who can consult for you let me know: https://www.linkedin.com/in/evanschalton/ -- might be more cost effective than hiring for the role